# Assign cookie with frame

Tags: javascript, cookies, frame

I'm a simple html with frames like that:

```
<frameset id="frames" ROWS="50%,50%" border="0" frameborder="0" bordercolor="black">
    <frame id="topFrame" src="www.example1.es" name="top" scrolling="yes" scrollbar="hidden">
    <frame id="downFrame" src="www.example2.com" name="bottom" scrolling="yes" scrollbar="hidden">
</frameset>
```

I'm persisting each frame with a cookie like this:

```
$.each(frames, function(index, value) { 
    var frame_value = $(value).attr("src");
    persistCookies(index, id);
});

function persistCookies(index, id) {
    var cookie = "cookie";  
    setCookie("cookie" + id, cookie , 20);  
}
```

When I change the URL from one frame, it's saving the new cookie but it's overwritting all cookies, not only the cookies which must overwritte. My question is, how can I "associate" the frame with the cookie I created before, so this way only overwrite the indicated cookie.

I hope I explained more or less.
Thanks!